# Get attribute value from same element method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a React component render like this:

```
return (
  <nav>
    <a href='/link1'>LINK 1</a>
    <a href='/link2'>LINK 2</a>
    <a href='/link3'>LINK 3</a>
  </nav>
)
```

Is it possible to reference the unique href attributes from a method called from the element, similar to this (pseudo code that doesn't work):

```
...

const func1 = function(target){
  if (target.href === '/link2') return 'bar'

  return 'baz'
}

return (
  <nav>
    <a href='/link1' className={func1(this)}>LINK 1</a>
    <a href='/link2' className={func1(this)}>LINK 2</a>
    <a href='/link3' className={func1(this)}>LINK 3</a>
  </nav>
)

...
```

Ideally the example above would render in the DOM something like this:

```
<a href='/link1' class='baz'>LINK 1</a>
<a href='/link2' class='bar'>LINK 2</a>
<a href='/link3' class='baz'>LINK 3</a>
```

I'd like to do it this way to keep it DRY -- avoiding the need to write href value twice (which in practice will be much longer than simply '/link1'.

I'm still picking up React, so if the answer is "no", or "you can do it but it's not good practice", I'd love to know.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can create link component, and pass getter function to it

```
function Link(props) {
  return <a href={props.href} className={props.getClassName(props.href)} />
}
```

Or you can for example, create array of links, and render them

```
const links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']

return (
  <nav>
    {links.map(link => <a href={link} className={getClassName(link)} />}
  </nav>
)
```

Comment: These are both great suggestions - thanks!  I'll leave the question open for a bit longer, and assuming no better answers mark yours as the one.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can storage the link info and iterate over it:

```
const links = [{href: "/link1", text: "LINK 1"}, {href: "/link2", text: "LINK 2", className: "bar"}, {href: "/link3", text: "LINK 3"}]


return (
  <nav>
    {links.map(({href, text, className}) => (<a href={href} className={className || "baz"}>{text}</a>))}
  </nav>
)
```